# Проблема с регулярным выражением (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, регулярные-выражения

Суть в том, что почему-то выводится только первый ББкод из сообщения (БД MySQL), все остальные почему-то просто срезается.
К примеру, есть сообщение: "Всем привет [id]1[/id]. Есть новое на [id]2[/id]"

Код:

```
function id($id){
$id = preg_replace('/\[id\]([0-9]+)\[\/id\]/', '$1', $id);
    $q = DB::$dbs->query("SELECT `id`,`name` FROM `station` WHERE `id` = '".$id."'");
        while($station = $q -> fetch())
        {
            return '[<a href="/'.$station[id].'">'.$station[name].'</a>]';
        }
}
```

Использую так:

```
echo id(message['id']);
```

Выводит:

"Всем привет [ссылка]. Есть новое на "

Почему так происходит?

Comment: ну так у вас  весь код  написан на случай одного id. и в запросе, и return после получения первой записи

Comment: @splash58, задумка была на все случаи [id]...[/id]

Comment: переписывайте - where in, и собирайте результаты в массив

Comment: `preg_match_all("/\[id\]([0-9]+)\[\/id\]/", $str, $matches); var_dump($matches);` - $matches[1] содержит все найденные id, в запросе `... WHERE id IN (". implode(',', $matches[1]) .")` и текст вместо return собирайте в переменную

Answer (score 0):

Вот возможное решение задачи:

```
<?php
function get_ids($str) {
    preg_match_all('/\[id\]([0-9]+)\[\/id\]/m', $str, $ids);
    return $ids[1];
}

function id_to_link($id){
    global $mysqli;
    
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT `id`,`name` FROM `station` WHERE `id` = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
    
    while($station = $stmt -> fetch())
    {
        return '[<a href="/'.$id.'">'.$name.'</a>]';
    }
}

$ids =  get_ids('Всем привет [id]1[/id]. Есть новое на [id]2[/id]');

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    echo id_to_link($id);
}
```

[PHP онлайн](https://phpize.online/?phpses=38f58487243ee257fcef22733c2fa9b9&sqlses=949eb03d53cfa6e58474b3326205dcf4&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)